# Reloading partial view with DisplayFor Recursion

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, recursion, partial-views

I have a partial view which loads a template and works fine. But when I refresh it using AJAX it renders the partial view out incorrectly.

My Main view has this in it:

```
<div id="OrgTreeViewDiv">
    @Html.Partial("_OrganisationTreeView", Model)
</div>
```

My Partial View:

```
<div id="StructureTree" class="k-header">
  <ul id="treeview">

    @foreach (var level in Model)
    {
        if (level.OrgLevel == 0)
        {
            foreach (var org in level.OrganisationsList)
            {
                @Html.DisplayFor(x => org);
            }

        }   
    }
  </ul>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#treeview").kendoTreeView();
});
</script>
```

And the display Template:

```
@model OrganisationViewModel
<li data-expanded="true">
    <span class="LevelSelector" LevelName="@Model.LevelName" OrgGuid="@Model.OrganisationGuid" Abbreviation="@Model.Abbreviation" Orglevel="@Model.OrganisationLevel">
        @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.OrganisationName)
    </span>
    <a href="#" class="DeleteOrg">Del</a>
    @if (Model.HasChildren)
    {
        @:<ul>  
            foreach (var child in Model.ChildOrganisations)
            {
                @Html.DisplayFor(x => child)
            }
        @:</ul>
    }

</li>
```

I am using the following clientside call

```
$('#OrgTreeViewDiv').load('@Url.Action("InsertOrganisationAbove","OrganisationAJAX")' + '?OrgGuid=' + OrgGuid + '&NewName=' + newName + '&Abbreviation=' + Abbreviation);
```

Though I have also tried this:

```
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: Url,
                timeout: 60000,
                tryCount: 0,
                retryLimit: 3,
                success: function (data) {
                    $("#OrgTreeViewDiv").html(data);
                },
                error: function (httpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    $(".Message").text("Error :" + textStatus + " " + errorThrown)
                }
            });
        });
```

Finally the controller looks like this:

```
public PartialViewResult InsertOrganisationAbove(string OrgGuid, string NewName, string Abbreviation)
        {
            List<OrganisationLevelViewModel> OrganisationLevelList = new List<OrganisationLevelViewModel>();
            //Do loads of stuff which all works fine
            return PartialView("_OrganisationTreeView", OrganisationLevelList);
        }
```

So what happens is it calls the Partial View fine but then does not go into the Display Template and so renders it all out as a list of Displayfields.

Where as I need it to recognise the DisplayTemplate and write it out as a .

It works fine on Pageload, it is just the AJAX call which is having this problem.

Any help?

Comment: The model for your display template is `OrganisationViewModel`, but your `InsertOrganisationAbove` action passes `List<OrganisationLevelViewModel>`. Is that a typo? If not, that's your problem. That means when retrieving the template via AJAX, you're eventually calling `DisplayFor` on `OrganisationLevelViewModel` instances rather than `OrganisationViewModel`.

Comment: Hi. Well noticed, I should have explained that. In the foreach loop org is an OrganisationViewModel. So thats not it unfortunately

Comment: No one able to help?